# Generate XML envelope body with desired prefix in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, soap

I have the following class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ConsultarInfoClienteABM"]
public class ConsultarInfoClienteABM
{
    [XmlElement("EBMHeader")]
    public EBMHeader EBMHeader { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DataArea")]
    public DataArea DataArea { get; set; }
}
```

Which is generating the following envelope:

[image]

This is the code i'm using to generate the envelope:

```
var envelope = SoapEnvelope.Prepare();
        envelope.Body(new ConsultarInfoClienteABM()
        {
            EBMHeader = new EBMHeader()
            {
                EBMID = "xxx"
            },
            DataArea = new DataArea()
            {
                CustomerID = "aaa",
                UDN = "1"
            }
        });
```

My problem is that i need to generate the xml body with a differente prefix other than Q1.

The desired prefix would be: V1 instead of Q1

I read that the namespace should define it, but what namespace should i use to generate v1?